# How can I use three Conv1d on the three axis of my 3*n matrix in Pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

The following is my CNN. The input of it is a (3,64) matrix, I want to use three convolution kernels to process the x,y,z axis respectively.

```
class Char_CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Char_CNN, self).__init__()
        self.convdx = nn.Conv1d(1, 12, 20)
        self.convdy = nn.Conv1d(1, 12, 20)
        self.convdz = nn.Conv1d(1, 12, 20)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(540, 1024)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024, 30)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(30, 13)

    def forward(self, x):
        after_convd = [self.convdx(x[:, :, 0]), self.convdy(x[:, :, 1]), self.convdz(x[:, :, 2])]
        after_pool = [F.max_pool1d(F.relu(value), 3) for value in after_convd]

        x = torch.cat(after_pool, 1)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = F.softmax(x)
        return x
```

But during the running of `loss = criterion(out, target)`, a RunTime Error occurs:

> RuntimeError: Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed.

I'm very new to pytorch so that I cannot find out the mistake of my code.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The way of convolution is okay. The problem is my labels were between 1 and 13, and the correct range is 0 to 12.
After modifying it, my CNN works successfully.
But as a fresher to Pytorch and deep learning, I guess my convolution mode can be clearer and easier. Welcome to point out my errors!

Comment: your question is unclear. the error you faced is because your criterion function expects the target labels as 0 to 12 but you are providing the labels as 1 to 13. can you provide more details of what you are doing? what are the inputs? please explain, so that we can help.

Comment: Sorry for that， the problem was solved and my code is running successfully.